# what is regsvr.exe

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, virus, process

Everytime I plug my flash drive on school. It gets infected by this regsvr.exe and many others. Even if my fd is already vaccinated by panda antivirus it still gets infected even if I'm not accessing it via the computer. I just plug it in without doing anything and it still gets infected. Is it possible to avoid it when plugging your fd to an infected computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole information is listed here:

http://www.file.net/process/regsvr.exe.html

> The file is an unknown file in the Windows folder. regsvr.exe is able to record inputs, monitor applications, manipulate other programs. Therefore the technical security rating is 70% dangerous, however also read the users reviews.

I also suggest to read this about how to remove it:

http://www.ehow.com/how_5157100_remove-regsvrexe.html

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest trying the steps here to remove the said file from your flash drive:

[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

As to whether it's possible to avoid it, I don't think it's possible (or at least I haven't seen it). As long as the system you're plugging the flash drive to is infected, your flash drive will get it too.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to avoid it when plugging your fd to an infected computer?

There are some flash drives with a hardware write protection switch like the ones on SD-Cards. If you can't find one, use a SD-Card with an flashdrive-sized cardreader.
Unless you can clean the infected computer there is nothing else you can do.